# PInvoke only works in 64 bit, when returning a struct

Tags: c#, c++, interop, pinvoke

I have the following C++ code, that compiles to a dll:

```
typedef struct _RGB {
    unsigned char R, G, B;
} RGB;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) RGB __stdcall TestMethod1() {
    RGB rgb{1,2,3};
    return rgb;
}
```

and am calling it in C# using:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var res = TestMethod1();
}

[DllImport(@"D:\Develop\res\VSProjects\ConsoleApp1\Debug\Dll1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
static extern RGB TestMethod1();

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct RGB { public byte R, G, B; }
```

When running it as x86, after building the dll as x86, I get an error `Attempted to read or write protected memory.`. In x64 it works fine.

When I use a managed/native debugger, I see it's crashing on `return rgb;`.

When changing the return type to a `long` (`int` in C#) it works fine even as x86.

The `RGB` struct [is blittable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/blittable-and-non-blittable-types) so why am I getting this issue?

Comment: You should add the [`Pack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack?view=netframework-4.8) parameter. `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]` to the StructLayout, because your struct is 3 bytes long. For c++ you should check the `#pragma pack(push, 1)`

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen No, that won't make any difference at all, because the struct contains 3 bytes and all possible alignments are the same. And it is in fact wrong because the C++ struct is not packed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I do not believe this is a duplicate, since the other question was returning a pointer, which obviously won't work. I am returning the struct itself, and nothing in that question explains why that won't work.

Comment: Fine. I read the C# code in that question which assumed the struct was returned by value. Anyway, you know the solution now.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My question remains unanswered, see my comment on Simon's answer.

Comment: It's difficult to know what you are looking for. It seems clear to me that there is an ABI mismatch. By val struct return values aren't pinned down in the x86 ABI so different tools do different things. Use the code in Simon's answer, or the code in HP's answer in the linked Q. That is, if you want to make this work.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My aim is not to make it work, I was already aware of methods to do so. I want to understand why my code doesn't work, despite Microsoft writing that complex types that contain only blittable types can be returned, without exception. I am unsettled to see inaccuracies in Microsoft's documentation.

Comment: If you want to understand it, you'll need to discover how the two sides of the binary interface operate.  That can be done, for example, by debugging the function call at the CPU/asm level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use struct for "complex" return types, prefer something like this:

C++:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall TestMethod2(RGB *prgb) {
    prgb->R = 1;
    prgb->G = 2;
    prgb->B = 3;
}
```

C#:

```
[DllImport(@"D:\smo\source\repos\ConsoleApplication4\Debug\Dll1.dll")]
static extern void TestMethod2(ref RGB rgb);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var rgb = new RGB();
    TestMethod2(ref rgb);
}
```

Note in your particular case, it fails because the structure size is 3, so you can make it work if you change the structure like this for example:

C++:

```
typedef struct _RGB {
    unsigned char R, G, B, A;
} RGB;
```

C#

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct RGB { public byte R, G, B, A; }
```

With this definition, the size will be 4, so the C++ compiler will generate a code that will return an int32 value instead of returning - probably - a reference to some internal memory that will be gone by the time execution reaches the .NET side. This is pure luck (or hack) and depends on the C++ compiler I guess.

Comment: [Microsoft writes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/blittable-and-non-blittable-types) that `Formatted value types that contain only blittable types` can be returned. It does not say `unless the size is 3`. Why should that matter?

Comment: @wezten - this is not a blittable vs non-bilittable issue. This is a "return value from a function from unmanaged to managed" issue. As I said, it works fine if you pass the structure by reference. All examples from Microsoft follow that pattern.

Comment: In that article it says `Structures that are returned from platform invoke calls must be blittable types. Platform invoke does not support non-blittable structures as return types.`. It then goes on to explain that complex types containing blittable types are themselves blittable, implying that they can be returned.

Comment: @wezten - the "return types" they are talking here are not to be confused with what a function returns at binary level. They're talking about ref and out types. Again, the value that a C stdcall or cdecl function returns in a 32bit process is a 32bits value, stored in the EAX, period (so when you pass a structure, the result beyond the compiler is undefined). It works fine to return a structure between two functions compiled with the same C compiler because it knows its own internals, but that's all.

Comment: Thank you, that really clears things up. Is passing a `LayoutKind.Sequential` struct as a parameter (by value) safe though?